# validate a string consiting only of letters, numbers and optional spaces

Tags: php, regex, validation

I have this function:

```
function validate_string_spaces_only($string) {
    if(preg_match("/^[\w ]+$]/", $string)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I want to match a string that consists only of letters and numbers with an optional space character. When I feed the above function a string containing only letters, numbers and spaces it fails every time. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `]` character in your regex near the end. Remove it and it should work.

`"/^[\w ]+$]/"` should be `"/^[\w ]+$/"`.

(Also note that `\w` typically allows underscores as well, which you may or may not want.)

Comment: ah yes completely missed that! THanks!

Answer (score 1):

This regex will:

- match a string that consists only of letters and numbers with an optional space character

`^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$`

[image]